# Can I use auto layout in a storyboard to position my views, then disable the constraints?

Tags: swift, animation, autolayout, storyboard

I'd like to perform an interactive gesture-based animation with my views that requires moving a view which is centered in the screen to the top-left corner of the screen. I can't seem to interpolate between the position of two different x/y constraints (only changing the constant), so as an alternative, I thought perhaps I could lay out the views in my storyboard, then animate them by changing the frame directly. Is there a good way to do this, or is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to *remove* them! Just deactivate them is enough.

If you have seen the docs, you should know that the `constraints` property of a `UIView` returns the constraints that it has as a `[NSLayoutConstraint]`. You just need to loop through this array and deactivate all the constraints!

```
for constraint in someView.constraints {
    constraint.active = false
}
```

Or using `forEach`:

```
someView.constraints.forEach { $0.active = false }
```

The advantage of deactivating constraints instead of removing them is that you can activate them again easily when you need it.

Comment: How does that forEach statement work? What does $0 mean?

Comment: @GoldenJoe It's another way of writing the `for in` loop. See the variable `constraint` that I declared in the `for in` loop? The `$0` in the `forEach` closure has roughly the same meaning. If you feel like this is too functional for you, stick with the `for in` loop.

Comment: @GoldenJoe Did it work for you? If it did, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Gimme some time. Working on it now.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would choose to animate constraint instead. Even if you cannot change the constraint constant for some reason, you can still remove the previous contraint and add a new one. 
To do so you'll need to :

1. Keep a reference to the constraint you want to change
2. remove it from the view
3. set the new constraint and add it to the view
4. keep the reference of that new constraint
5. Animate with :

   UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
           self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
       }

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't produce an interactive animation.

Comment: Why? Have you try it?

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. I am making an animation that progresses as the user pans up and down the screen. It's not a "press a button and watch the animation" type animation.